# Why are the words hundred, thousand, million, and trillion singular after plural numbers?

Tags: grammatical-number

Can anyone give a grammatical explanation why the words hundred, thousand, million, and trillion are singular after plural numbers?

For example, why can't we say *three hundreds* or *4 thousands* or *five millions*, etc?

One of my students asked me and all I could say is that it is an exception to the rule of bringing a plural word after a plural number!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57812/a-few-more-hundred-vs-hundreds

Comment: Besides [A few more hundred vs hundreds](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57812) mentioned before, see [Millions versus million](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16350)

Comment: It is also true for "dozen", "gross", "score" and sometimes (especially in older writings) for "pair" as well.

Comment: But Google Ngrams seems to show that in Indian English, it's not as true for "lakh" and "crore". So the usage is "two lakh fifty thousand", but "I need three lakhs of ...".

Comment: What's the next word?

Comment: @SrJoven if you don't add the @ in front of their name, that user will never be notified. And I see the comment was posted in 2012, so you probably have to google that line for yourself :)

Comment: @SrJoven I thought you were referring to Peter Shore's comment.

Answer (score 11):

This phenomenon - the uninflected plural of numerals - is a remnant of Old English. In Old English, words like **hund** "hundred" and **þusend** "thousand" were indeclinable. That is, they did not change form based on case or number.

Today this remains but only in some limited situations - specifically, when the number word is preceded by a determiner (**a**, **one**, another number). This is also the case in English's sister language [Frisian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frisian_languages) (you knew English had a sister language, right?), where [tûzen, etc., don't take a plural form](http://www.languagesandnumbers.com/how-to-count-in-west-frisian/en/fry/).

Answer (score 9):

There is not necessarily a logical grammatical justification.  In the case of *million*, usage patterns have shifted.

#### "Two millions" *vs.* "Two million"

According to Google Ngram, "two millions" has long been the standard expression.  However, starting around 1850, its usage declined while "two million" rose in popularity.  Around 1920, "two million" became the new norm, and today "two millions" is rarely used.

[image: Google Ngram of "Two millions" vs. "Two million"]

#### "Two thousands", "Two hundreds"

In contrast, neither "two thousands" nor "two hundreds" has ever been accepted usage.

[image: Google Ngram of "Two thousand(s)" and "Two hundred(s)"]

---

If I had to speculate on the reason for the difference, it is probably because *million* has Latin origins, whereas *hundred* and *thousand* have Germanic origins.  Therefore, the Old English-based inflection rules have always applied to *hundred* and *thousand*, as @MarkBeadles says, but the French-based rules for *million* have only recently started giving way.

Comment: http://books.google.it/books?id=oJU3AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA597&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&sig=ACfU3U0Jzpy95LubmyToG2LCOdORNdQTUA&ci=31%2C1205%2C429%2C362&edge=0  The snippet has "fifty millions" and "two millions".

Comment: [“Millions” versus “million”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16350/millions-versus-million) You could also post an answer there. This [link](http://books.google.it/books?id=oJU3AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA597&dq=%22two+millions%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BO5aVLyZA8O7Pcf2gbAM&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22two%20millions%22&f=false) directs you to the snippet I posted in my comment.

Answer (score 8):

I've always thought that when the words *hundred, thousand, million* and *trillion* are used after a specific number, they are part of that number. I know that number *fifteen*, for example, signifies the plural form of the noun that follows, but there's no need to pluralise the word *fifteen*. Similarly, it looks logical to me not to pluralise the words that form the number. So *two hundred* and the like is ruled by this logic. Note that the same thing happens with the (less frequent) words *dozen* and *score*.

When the number is not specific and you want to talk about *a few hundreds of people*, for example, you then pluralise *hundred* because you aren't naming a specific number. This is the case when the non-specific number is followed by the preposition **of**. If you say *a few hundred people*, where no preposition intervenes, then *hundred* behaves in the same way as when the number is specified. A possible explanation for this could be that it follows the rule that forms *two hundred* because the construct is the same, while the use of the preposition **of** changes things.

Answer (score 3):

They don't get an *s* because that's not what they're called.

300 is called *three hundred*. That is its name. You could say you are counting the number of hundreds, but you're not really, you're just naming something. We could have ended up calling it thirtyty, or something, but we haven't.

Also you can say *3 hundreds* or *2 thousands*, when you are counting them.

> I have 3 hundreds, 14 fifties, and 12 ones.

Comment: This doesn't really explain why we say "five dozen" or "three score". Those are not names for a number ... the name for that number is "sixty". But we don't pluralize "dozen".

Comment: @PeterShor then the reason for that is different.

Comment: It's exactly the same phenomenon.

Comment: @PeterShor I don't see how.

Comment: You could say that the grammatical rule is that you don't pluralize "number words" when preceded by numbers or the words "few" and "several", where "number words" are "gross", "score", "dozen", "hundred", "thousand", "million", "billion", "trillion", etc. [Before 1850 or so](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=six+pair%2C+six+pairs&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), "pair" was also a "number word". And "head" is a "number word" when applied to livestock (i.e., fifty head of cattle).

Comment: @PeterShor That's one way to interpret the question. I have interpreted from the point of view of naming numbers. Your interpretation is a duplicate of the question linked by Shyam in the comments. Names of numbers that don't end in *s*, don't end in *s*.

Comment: @PeterShor: To pluralize a number word would emphasize that the items in question were separated into distinct groups. The phrase "two dozens of donuts" would specifically indicate two distinct groups of twelve donus each, while "two dozen donuts" might be delivered in two boxes of twelve, or one box of 24. In most cases it will either be unimportant whether things are grouped as twelves, or will be sufficiently "obviously" important as to go without saying (e.g. a florist receiving an order for "three dozen roses" would deliver three bundles of twelve in the absence of contrary instructions.)

Answer (score 0):

The only words you can put in plural are nouns. Cardinal and ordinal numbers aren't nouns.
Except for example: the 90s were great

Comment: How is that an "except"?

Comment: you are right. It's a noun and not a cardinal number. I shoudn't have used the word except.